# synchronised paint in C#?

Tags: c#, database, synchronization, paint

I am thinking of making a little program in which two users would have a drawing canvas and on which they could both draw over the internet and the image would be synchronised. if i draw a line ..the user on the other computer would see it instantly.

I was hoping that some of you could have an any advice or documentation, or suggestion on how i could achieve something like this.

Personally..i was thinking of using a sql server, finding a way to draw and save an image..and convert it to bytes..save it in a database and constantly downloading the image, but that could kill the server.

BTW... this is a windows forms app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have the bandwidth to transmit the entire image that quickly.

You don't want to transmit the image at all since, for example, if you paint a stroke over an area at the same time the other person does, you'll have no way to reconcile the two paint strokes in the same area.

The best thing to do would be to define tools and capture user input, then transmit the user actions with timestamps to keep track of who did what first.  For example, if you use a Pen tool, and drag it across the screen to create a line, you would want to transmit information like:

- User
- DateTime stamp
- Tool (Pen/Brush/etc.)
- Color
- Array of points from where they started to where they stopped drawing

This action can then be re-created on the other client(s).

If you are looking to do something like this, make sure you do the client side/single user code first.  If you don't have a canvas drawing application yet, don't get ahead of yourself with the networking portion.  Just design it in a way where each action can be reduced to data as shown above.  So you'll have the data needed to transmit and reproduce the action.

Comment: uh...thanks..you just shed some light upon me.So let's say i keep all that data.How am i supposed to transmit this data?I am guessing the sql database idea wouldn't be good because it would probably KO the server because it would need to check for new data

Comment: I am not sure if there are better alternatives, but Windows Sockets using the System.Net namespace works well for low-latency client/server apps.

Comment: thanks man...you've been a real help.i am gonna get to it ..hope i wont need anymore help

Comment: No problem.  If you do just ask a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

[Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) would be a good solution for this. With Socket.IO there's no need to poll a database or persist data in any form. Every-time the user draws something, you'd want to send the canvas data to the server and the server would then immediately send it to the client.

For the drawing area you'd want to use [HTML5 canvas.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) There's a nice tutorial [here](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-simple) about getting a basic drawing canvas up and running.

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, Jon Gallaway posted an [article on his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/10/26/using-node-js-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-iisnode.aspx) about getting up and running with Node.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.the thing is that i am trying to do this in a windows forms application

Comment: Apologies, I assumed you were using ASP!